# AWS S3 image upload size restriction

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, next.js

I am trying to follow the tutorial on this [repository](https://github.com/leerob/nextjs-aws-s3). It is using nextjs and AWS S3 to upload images. What I don't get is that the image size is restricted to 1MB. Why is this the case? How can I increase this size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit is enfored [here](https://github.com/leerob/nextjs-aws-s3/blob/main/pages/api/upload-url.js#L19):

```
    Conditions: [
      ['content-length-range', 0, 1048576], // up to 1 MB
    ],
```

So I guess removing the `Conditions` should be enough to overcome the limit.

Comment: OMG Thank you so much. I will select this answer in 10 min.

Comment: @luke.lcim No problem. Glad I could help. And thanks.